# Initiate full redraw of ListView

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps

Currenlty I change ListView behavior at runtime ( Horizontal list in normal mode and vertical list in snapped mode). My code ( launched at SizeChanged event ):

```
myViewState = ApplicationView.Value;
ScrollViewer scroller = FindChild < ScrollViewer>( itemsListView );
WrapGrid wrapper = FindChild < WrapGrid >( itemsListView );
if ( scroller != null && wrapper != null )
{
    if ( myViewState == ApplicationViewState.Snapped )
    {
    wrapper.Orientation = Orientation.Horizontal;
    scroller.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility = ScrollBarVisibility.Disabled;
    scroller.VerticalScrollBarVisibility = ScrollBarVisibility.Auto;
    scroller.HorizontalScrollMode = ScrollMode.Disabled;
    scroller.VerticalScrollMode = ScrollMode.Enabled;
    }
    else
    {
    wrapper.Orientation = Orientation.Vertical;
    scroller.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility = ScrollBarVisibility.Auto;
    scroller.VerticalScrollBarVisibility = ScrollBarVisibility.Disabled;
    scroller.HorizontalScrollMode = ScrollMode.Enabled;
    scroller.VerticalScrollMode = ScrollMode.Disabled;                      
    }
   // itemsSource change
}
```

However ListView does not update items well. Here is example: 
[image: screenshot]

When I change itemsSource right after the ListView properties change - it works well. However, I would like to avoid it and update ListView internally.

Comment: Try moving the wrapper orientation change to after scroller changes. Try setting scroller off sets to 0 after changes.

Comment: HorizontalOffset and VerticallOffset is read-only. Changing the positions have no effect (already tried). InvalidateScrollerInfo also doesn't work.